# How to handle PUT/DELETE requests in Symfony2 FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

When I use `PUT` or `DELETE` requests on rest route generate by `FOSRestBundle`, it returns

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /app_dev.php/api/resources/3 on this server. Additionally, a
>   403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When I use `GET` or `POST` then it works just fine!

Here is my rest config:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { prefer_extension: false, priorities: ['json','xml','html'], fallback_format: json }
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
        formats:
            xml:    true
            json:   true
        templating_formats:
            html:   true
        mime_types:
            json:   ['application/json', 'application/x-json']
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    body_listener:  true
```

And my rest controller:

```
/**
 * @Rest\View
 */
public function putResourceAction(Request $request, $id)
{

    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
```

It throws `403` only when I use `putResourceAction` or `deleteResourceAction`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does it work when you annotate the action with `@Method("PUT")`?

Comment: @Gordon No. It gives same error. Even without using `@Method("PUT")` the `debug:router` says the accepted method is `PUT`. Is there anything to do with file permissions in any way?

Comment: Can you check whether your webserver allows PUT requests. See http://serverfault.com/questions/438183/how-to-enable-all-http-methods-in-an-apache-http-server or https://bjornjohansen.no/restrict-allowed-http-methods-in-nginx

Comment: @Gordon I'm using apache and I checked all relevant config files and it doesn't seem to limit any methods.

Comment: then I dont know. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is experiencing this kind of problem with PUT, DELETE or other methods unavailable, try adding this to .htaccess:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require method DELETE GET POST PUT OPTIONS
</RequireAny>

<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

---

Other way described [here](https://htaccessbook.com/control-request-methods/) to allow only specified methods

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(DELETE|GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|POST|PROPFIND|PUT) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, check allowed methods in your web server configuration.

[Information for apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_allowmethods.html)

[For Nginx](https://bjornjohansen.no/restrict-allowed-http-methods-in-nginx)